# STM32L4 μs delay

Tags: stm32, delay, 1-wire, onewire

I am trying to implement a [onewire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Wire) protocol on an STM32L432KCU, so I need quite precise timing (need delay precise as 2μs).

I was wondering if there is any way to do this using the HAL drivers (since the rest of the project I am working on is using HAL) or if any other workaround exists.

I have already tried to use [this](https://github.com/keatis/dwt_delay) library but it seems not to work for stm32l4 series.

Comment: Do you have any timer to spare?

Comment: DWT based delay should work for ARM Cortex M3 - M4 STM32s. Did you try to inspect the author's code? `"change to whatever MCU you use"` - line 23 file `dwt_delay.c`

Comment: If you need to use HAL drivers you could probably implement it with timer and DMA. Not sure how complex implementation would be as I didnt try anything similar.

Comment: Unless you are trying to use the overdrive mode, you are substantially overestimating the required speed and time precision.

Answer (score 1):

[HAL library functions are too slow for tasks involving precise timing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440516/stm32-spi-slow-compute), and the MCU in the linked post is twice as fast as yours, so it'd be even worse. For a bit-banging 1-wire implementation only 3 register accesses are needed: `GPIOx->IDR` to read the port, `GPIOx->BSRR` to output a bit, and `SysTick->VAL`, see below.

If you can't get `DWT->CYCCNT` to work, there is the `SysTick->VAL` counter, counting system clock cycles from the value in `SysTick->LOAD` downwards to `0`, that can used to measure short intervals, just keep in mind that it gets reset once every millisecond (assuming you didn't mess with the HAL SysTick configuration).

If you have a free UART TX pin, you can try implementing the procedure in [Maxim Tutorial 214 Using a UART to Implement a 1-Wire Bus Master](https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN214.pdf). I've found that it works best with the reset pulse sent at 7407 baud, and the data at 133333 baud. See also [application note 27](https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN27.pdf) for the CRC algorithm if you don't have this already.

Comment: This doesn't have to be anywhere near as precise as the asker thinks, a delay loop should work